# Increase space between lines of glossed text, gb4e

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, linguistics, gb4e, cgloss4e

I'm using gb4e in report class. I'd like to format the glossed examples created using gb4e. There are three lines in my glossed example: The original text and the gloss, which are presented in one block, and the translation, which is set off from the original text and gloss.

At the moment, there is a gap between the original text/gloss block and the translation, which is good. But when the original text is longer than one line, the text wraps round and starts again on the next line, with no gap between the new line and the preceding lines of original and glossed text.

Is there a way to increase the space between the lines of original and glossed text when they wrap around the page? I've looked through the documentation, but I can't see anything.

Here is a picture of what my current output is, and what I'd like to format: 
[image: gb4e]

And here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex \gll kata-kata ini terlalu panjang, tidak ada spasi untuk kata-kata ini, saya tidak tahu harus bikin apa ka \\
word-\textsc{redup} this too long \textsc{neg} exist space for word-\textsc{redup} this \textsc{1sg} \textsc{neg} know should do what \textsc{tag} \\ 
\glt `These words are too long, there isn't enough space for these words, I don't know, what I should do?'
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Workaround: put a big invisible character in the line, e.g., `word-\textsc{redup} \phantom{\Huge{A}}this too long \textsc{neg}`

Comment: and the same with correct alignment: `\ex \gll kata-kata {} ini` (...) `word-\textsc{redup} \vphantom{\Huge{A}} this`